# Dreamweaver doesn't show all code hints

Tags: dreamweaver, three.js, hints

Example in Dreamweaver CS6:

```
<script src="libs/Three.js"></script> 
<script>
  var scene = null, 

  function init(){
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.                       //a few code hints show up, not all
    scene.rotatation.x += 0.01;  //this one exists, but code hints doesn't find it


  }
  function move(){
    scene. //no code hints show up

  }
</script>
```

So my questions are:

1. in move(), the reason code hints doesn't show up is probably because they haven't been initalized in init() yet. Is there a way to make them show up in move()?
2. Why doesn't the code hints show scene.rotation? How do I make it show all variables/methods?

This is not just a problem for Dreamweaver, it's the same in other web builders I've tried.

This is what I mean by code hints if you're wondering: https://i.stack.imgur.com/soCYo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Choosing a good text editor and workflow is very important and can affect your productivity a lot. I would suggest using a different text editor.

[Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) as amazing but for three.js code hints you will have to install plugins.
[Web Storm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) is another great editor with intelligent hints and color coding.